# Java Custom Serialization and Deserialization with Bit size definitions

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, ethernet

**The problem:**
I need to implement a network input reader from an electronic device which has fixed definitions of a packet format. It has a header, footer and data body. The fields in the packet are defined in term of bits.

**Example:**
The field sequence_number variable is the bits numbered 8 to 31 and ack_status is bit 32. How do I create a custom serialization function so that I can convert a java object to and from a byte[] read from a packet?

**In a 32 Bit Packet**

StartOfPacketHeader 4bits

CommandCode         4bits

SequenceNumber      23bits

AckStatus           1bit

How do I make a Java wrapper class for this object with a byte[] constructor and a toBytes() method.

Using the Serializable Interface has no control on individual data sizes. The data sizes may be odd values like a 3-bit or 18-bit variable. I cannot specify the length of the variables in terms of bits.

**What I have done so far:**

The source actually sends unsigned integers, meaning Java int type cannot handle its entire range. I need to define all data types as long to handle all cases. I have used the BitSet class to carry out byte[] to Long conversion but it's just too tedious and confusing as bitset reverses the bit order to Little Endian by default.

**Summary:**

How do I convert to my object from the bytes[] I read from the network and vice versa with custom definitions for each field in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` for this, with a `BufferedInputStream` or `BufferedOutputStream` under them respectively for efficiency purposes. The bit fields you will have to program yourself, but these classes provide all the Java primitives in network byte order.

For the packet you posted, you need something like this:

```
class Packet
{
    private byte    header;
    private byte    commandCode;
    private int     sequenceNumber;
    private boolean ackStatus;

    void    write(DataOutput out) throws IOException
    {
        int wirePacket = header|(commandCode << 4)|(sequenceNumber << 8);
        if (ackStatus)
        {
            wirePacket |= 0x80000000;
        }
        out.writeInt(wirePacket);
    }

    static Packet   read(DataInput in) throws IOException
    {
        Packet  packet = new Packet();
        int wirePacket = in.readInt();
        packet.header = (byte)(wirePacket & 0x0f);
        packet.commandCode = (byte)((wirePacket >>> 4) & 0x0f);
        packet.sequenceNumber = (wirePacket >>> 8) & 0x7FFFFF;
        packet.ackStatus = (wirePacket & 0x80000000) != 0;
        return packet;
    }
    // getters and setters. The setters must ensure that the values don't go out of range.
}
```

Comment: Could you quote an example?

Comment: I am unable to reconcile those two claims.

Comment: My question was handling bit level serialisation, I already know how to handle streams and carry out the basic object to byte conversions

Comment: How can I improve this question?

Comment: It's not clear what you need, if this isn't it. How to mask and bit-shift?

Comment: I have edited my question. I need a way to use non-conventional bit size definitions in my wrapper class. Like 3 bit, 18bit variables instead of the primitives.

Comment: Too vague. You need to provide a concrete example of a frame and what it consists of.

Comment: Have a look at the example

Comment: Thanks @EJB this was what I was looking for